# what is the minimum resolution we can set for webrtc video?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I am testing a peer to peer video chat app using webrtc. when I set the video contraints as

```
var video_constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        maxHeight: 120,
        maxWidth: 160 
    },
    optional: []
};

window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: video_constraints
}, onSuccess, onError);
```

this fires onError. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote from [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143631#c9](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143631#c9):

> GetUserMedia constraints are matched with a fixed list of resolutions independent on what the camera actually support. The list is fixed and used on all platforms.

```
1280, 720,
960, 720,
640, 360,
640, 480,
320, 240,
320, 180
```

This means your constraints will fail.

Constraints are also documented in Harald Alvestrand's [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-alvestrand-constraints-resolution-00).