# Change the quality webRTC

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

This question is not asking about [**resolutions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804851/what-is-the-minimum-resolution-we-can-set-for-webrtc-video) and frameRates on `getUserMedia()`.

It is about how to reduce/increase the quality **of the one frame** in video when using `getUSerMedia()`.

Here [***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/App7P/11/) of using getUserMedia().

How to change the Quality of the video? `//Please Fiddle answer.`

code:

```
var video_constraints = {mandatory: {
       maxWidth: 320,
       maxHeight: 240,
       maxAspectRatio:4/3,
       maxFrameRate:1
      },
      optional: [ ]
 };

var constraints = {audio: true, video: video_constraints };
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: What quality are you talking about? Quality of sending? Quality of local video play? If not resolution or framerate, what are you wanting?

Comment: this will let you control the quality of the stream during a call https://stackoverflow.com/a/74600584/12771945

Answer (score 8):

If not resolution or frame rate, I assume you're either talking about bit rate or camera settings (white balance, exposure, contrast, etc.).

The video stream provided by `getUserMedia` should give you uncompressed video at the highest quality available from the camera hardware. There is no way to adjust the camera settings; they are fully automatic, controlled by the camera driver and/or operating system. If you want to adjust the image, you can process it with canvas, using either a 2d or webgl context. There are [multiple](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/) [libraries](https://github.com/evanw/glfx.js) available to help you with that.

As for the bit rate, this only becomes an issue when you are transmitting the video over peer connection. This is also done adaptively and automatically.

> Regardless of the quality and size of provided media streams, the network stack implements its own flow and congestion control algorithms: every connection starts by streaming audio and video at a low bitrate (<500 Kbps) and then begins to adjust the quality of the streams to match the available bandwidth.

Source: *[High Performance Browser Networking](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch18.html#_delivering_media_with_srtp_and_srtcp)*

Comment: You can put a cap on bitrate for a webrtc connection by added a bitrate attribute to the SDP before setting it as local and sending it to the remote party.

Comment: @MoathHowari What exactly do you mean by video quality?

Comment: @brianchirls Video quality means video quality
what exactly you mean by exactly ?

Comment: There are many factors that go into video quality. Resolution, bit rate, color fidelity, noise, etc.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712224/how-to-control-bandwidth-in-webrtc-video-call